# function returns not expected value

Tags: c, arrays

i have a function that counts arithmetic mean of even numbers in an array.

```
int func(int *x, int length)
{
  float even_sum = 0;
  int even_num;
  int i;
  float result;
  for (i = 0; i<length; i++) 
 {
    if (x[i] % 2 == 0)
     {
      even_sum = even_sum + x[i];
      even_num++;
     }
 }
 result = even_sum/even_num;
 return result;
```

}

giving an array `1 2 2 1` i expect to receive 2 as mean, but i keep getting 0 as result. Where is a mistake in my code?

Comment: What compiler are you using that didn't warn you about using an uninitialized variable? Or, why did you ignore the valuable warning your compiler provided? A huge percentage of all C questions on Stack Overflow  could be eliminated if people simply paid attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: http://ideone.com/J02bRM

Comment: The behaviour of the function is undefined since `even_num` is never initialised before its value is retrieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int func(int *x, int length)
{
  float even_sum = 0;
  int even_num; // <-- uninitialized, could be anything!
  int i;
  float result;
  for (i = 0; i<length; i++) 
 {
    if (x[i] % 2 == 0)
     {
      even_sum = even_sum + x[i];
      even_num++; // <-- adding 1 to anything yields undefined behavior 
     }
 }
 result = even_sum/even_num; // <-- even more undefined behavior
 return result;
}
```

You initialized some, but not all of your variables. It's best to get in the habit of setting your variables to sensible starting values, just as you do here with `float even_sum = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `even_num=0`

If you don't initialize variables, they can have garbage values.

In your case, `even_num` has a huge values, greater that `even_sum` causing your result to be `0`.

Answer (score 1):

@Pbd is correct. If you have the latest version of `gcc` installed and use the command line flags `-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow` when compiling, it will give you a warning for uninitialized values.

Answer (score -1):

I think The only problem in your code is when you are passing int array into this function. Apart from that everything looks fine. I ran the code by initialling the 'x' array and it is working fine.